# How to query Google App Engine datastore and pass results to new pages?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Given the following Python code excerpt from Google App Engine that demonstrates my working datastore model, how can I query my model entities and show the results on new pages called `showall.html` and `showlist.html`?

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class PersonInfo(db.Model):
    firstname = db.StringProperty()

    lastname = db.StringProperty()

    book = db.StringProperty()

    email = db.StringProperty()

    phone = db.StringProperty()

    os = db.StringProperty()

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
```

[...Submission form handler stuff...]

```
class Register(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        personinfo = PersonInfo()
        firstname = self.request.get('firstname')
        lastname = self.request.get('lastname')
        phone = self.request.get('phone')
        book = self.request.get('book')
        email = self.request.get('email')
        os = self.request.get('os')

        #This puts stuff in database
        personinfo.firstname=firstname
        personinfo.lastname=lastname
        personinfo.phone=phone
        personinfo.book=book
        personinfo.email=email
        personinfo.os=os 
        personinfo.put()


        self.response.out.write("""
    <ul>
      <li><a href = "showall.html">Show All People Registered</a></li>
      <li><a href = "showlist.html">Show People Inside This List</a></li>
    </ul>""")

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
[('/', MainPage),
('/sign', Register),
    ],debug=True)

def main():
   run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Queries and Indexes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html):

```
# The Query interface constructs a query using instance methods.
q = Person.all()
q.filter("last_name =", "Smith")
q.filter("height <", 72)
q.order("-height")

# The GqlQuery interface constructs a query using a GQL query string.
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Person " +
                "WHERE last_name = :1 AND height < :2 " +
                "ORDER BY height DESC",
                "Smith", 72)

# The query is not executed until results are accessed.
results = q.fetch(5)
for p in results:
  print "%s %s, %d inches tall" % (p.first_name, p.last_name, p.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. In google app engine you cannot write to the filesystem so you cannot store the results statically. What you could do is,

```
    self.response.out.write("""
<ul>
  <li><a href = "showall">Show All People Registered</a></li>
  <li><a href = "showlist">Show People Inside This List</a></li>
</ul>""")
```

Now create handler for showall and showlist, such as showallhandler,showlisthandler and
write the response using these handlers. Another reply here shows how to query database.
Just self.response.write(database query results) in each handlers.